# Jalali Calendar in fullcalendar

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar, momentjs, jalali-calendar

I use `fullcalendar` (fullcalendar.io) on my website.

My website has another language that needs Jalali calendar. So I try to change `fullcalendar` format to jalali because I see that this script uses `moment.js` and `moment.js` has an option to use jalali date.

I can't find out how to switch and use this calendar in jalali format.

Comment: It is not currently officially supported - https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/1813

Comment: Corrected spelling/grammar

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found Solution on Github, `Natico` convert fullcalendar to persian language and also add Jalali calendar with add `moment-jalali.js`:

https://github.com/Natico/fullcalendar-Jalaali/

Comment: The jalaali calendar has a lot of bugs because it doesn't convert internally gregorian dates to jalaali dates.