Persian / Shamsi / Jalaali for Reactjs (Months be separate and be based on Jalaali)
I want to have fullcalendar in reactjs with Jalaali date which shows each month separately. Now it shows me e.g "فروردین - اردیبهشت" but i want these months separately e.g "فروردین". I tried moment and moment-jalaali libraries but they just change the language.
    moment.locale('fa');

    <FullCalendar
                    plugins={[dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
                    initialView="dayGridMonth"
                    dayHeaderFormat={{weekday: 'long'}}
                    locale={'fa-IR'}
                    firstDay={6}
    />


https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/1813

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42182989/jalali-calendar-in-fullcalendar

More info here . In other words, Jalali is not fully supported yet, you may need to be patient.

P.S. See also [ask], and How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users? - did you look into this issue much, or at all, before posting?
